# How do I recycle a fragment?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a fragment that i want to use with the same code but generated for each titles i have with another database reference path .

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unu_fragment, container, false);

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_unu_recycler);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        mRef = mDatabase.getReference(restName).child("Meniu").child(CategoryAdapter.category).child(*SUBCATEGORY*);
...
```

I have a `RecyclerView` that follow this path and populate the fragment with some items but i need to populate every tab I have , and each tab has different `mRef` path as you can see in that `.child(*SUBCATEGORY*)` .

And this is how i generated the tabs :

```
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String key = child.getKey();
                adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentUnu(),key);
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        }
                @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

How should i proceed in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but from what i understood is that you want to have different reference path for different Tabs while  using the same Fragment Class for each fragment child in the hosting ViewPager.

if that is your case :

create a public getter method **in the class that has the viewPager widget** **in its** **layout:**

```
        //will return the current position of the Tab
         public int getViewPagerCurrentPosition(){
           return viewpager.getCurrentItem()
        }
```

In your Fragment **CHILD** Class (Where you have your recyclerview) :

If the hosting class is an **activity**:

```
int position = (CAST:NAME_OF_THE_ACTIVITY)getActivity().getViewPagerCurrentPosition()
```

If the hosting class is a **fragment**:

```
int position = (CAST:NAME_OF_THE_FRAGMENT)  getParentFragment().getViewPagerCurrentPosition()
```

Now, you can set the condition to assign the right reference path based on having the current position of the tab

Keep in mind that the position starts from 0

if(position==0){...}else ...

or switch(position)

> **UPDATE**(another *possible* Solution) (I'm assuming you need the childKey inside the fragment)

1-INSIDE YOUR FRAGMENT create this factory method (allows us to pass argument to the fragment):

```
private static final String ARG_CHILDKEY= "child_key"//or any string you want;
public static FragmentUnu newInstance(String key) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_CHILDKEY, key);

        FragmentUnu fragment = new FragmentUnu();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

2-Update the following:

```
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String key = child.getKey();
                adapter.AddFragment(FragmentUnu.newInstance(key),key);
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        }
                @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

3-back to your FragmentUnu :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String key=  getArguments().getString(ARG_CHILDKEY);
}
```

Now you have the key in your fragment

Comment: I don't know who the hosting activity is , i mean i tried with the activity i think it is but it doesn't find the method ```getViewPagerCurrentPosition()```

Comment: I tried with ```(*Activity with the ValueEventList as i wrote above in the code*) getActivity().getViewPager..```

Comment: `getViewPagerCurrentPosition()` you **should** add the following method (and make sure it is **public**).

Comment: This method is not part of Android sdk, you should add it manually where you have the viewPager variable

Comment: By casting, the system is supposed to find the method, that's why i am suggesting that this method is not being added

Comment: I added the method as u said , but it doesn't work , i'm getting an error that the method doesn't exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205976/discussion-between-hady-salhab-and-aka-mishu).